# Why can't I access any of my Exchange 2013 cmdlets in the EMS?

Tags: exchange-2013, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Exchange 2013 CU3 installed and I can't access any of the Exchange cmdlets. When I try to run any of them from an elevated EMS I get the dreaded:

> is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The account I am using is a Domain Admin and has no mailbox. I do have an Exchange 2010 sp3 server in my organization that I will be migrating away from very soon.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Google-Fu figured it out! in the EMS I had to type: `add-pssnapin *exchange* -erroraction SilentlyContinue`